# Use $.get() without dollar sign $

Tags: jquery, database, wordpress, load, advanced-custom-fields

I Got this lines in my Javascript code, and I Cannot use JQuery the $dollar-way, and get in this case doesn't works... I don't receive either the console.log message.

```
jQuery(document).get(full_event_editor_url, function(text){
    console.log('We can begin to work...');
    // code
});
```

I need a solution to access another url page to get values, I don't want to load it; only get values inside the function keys.

I tried to use *load()* function too, but didn't work. I'm working on wordpress theme. My requeriments on JQuery I cannot solve.

Which is the best way to only access another page a time and receive some values.

Comment: Why did you add `(document)`?

Comment: because jQuery().get(... or jQuery.get(... doesn't works either

Comment: Why don't they work?

Comment: that's what i wanna know :(

Comment: Add error handling. Look at your console.
 Do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

$ is just an alias for jQuery. If you have another variable already using $, you can call $.noConflict() to prevent conflicts.

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Try  `jQuery.get(full_event_editor_url).always(response=> console.log(response));`

Putting your callback function as a parameter of .get() will fail silently, whereas .always() will let you troubleshoot the issue regardless what it returns.

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ under **The jqXHR Object**